# How do I un-pair Apple Magic Keyboard 2 from a Mac that I don't have available?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I received a used Magic Keyboard 2 which was not un-paired from the previous Mac it was paired with.

I found a question that explains how to un-pair and re-pair the old Magic Keyboard (with batteries and power button), but haven't found a solution for the Magic Keyboard 2 yet.

How do I get this keyboard paired to a new Mac? I'm running macOS Mojave (10.14).

Comment: Try to turn off the keyboard and remove the batteries.

Comment: @harrymc As [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Keyboard): “It has a sealed non-replaceable rechargeable Lithium-ion battery which is charged through a Lightning Connector in the middle rear of the keyboard.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plug it into the new Mac with a Lightning Cable, that'll cause it to pair with the computer it's wired to.